# Regular express to match `command--o1--o2--o3`

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `command--o1--o2--o3` ( command,o1,o2,o3 are arbitrary words)

And I want get `[o1, o2, o3]` though a Regular Expression(Not a array operation or other ways. JUST only use Regular Expression).

Is there any idea to accomplish this !?

Comment: What language are you using ? What's exactly the rule for the matching ?

Comment: So like this? https://regex101.com/r/gN0gP3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript, and assuming you want all strings after a `--`, you may do

```
var things = str.split(/--/).slice(1)
```

If you just want to get the 2 characters words following `--`, then you may use

```
var things = str.match(/--\w\w/g).map(function(s){ return s.slice(2) })
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I want to get. But I'm just wondering can this be done by JUST RegExp at one time??

Comment: Depends on your exact rules for matching. But probably not, as `match` doesn't return the submatchs (`exec` does but you'd have too loop).